# Android receiving json, buffer isn't filled properly

Tags: java, android, json, buffer, httpurlconnection

I have a symfony webservice returning the content of a database table as json.

This code comes directly from the [Android HttpUrlConnection tutorials](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) themselves.

1. When called from the webbrowser, it works as verified by json checking tools
2. No escape characters or \n anywhere
3. The buffer cuts off after 1190 characters
4. Shorter json responses work flawlessly

   org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at character 50000 of... {my jason goes on for a while and is terminated by ����������������������������������������� which I assume represents the empty char[] section

This is where it goes wrong somehow, the reader isn't filling the buffer properly

```
// Reads an InputStream and converts it to a String.
public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException {
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
    char[] buffer = new char[len];
    reader.read(buffer);
    return new String(buffer);
}
```

HttpUrlConnection call code:

```
 /*
Given a URL, establishes an HttpUrlConnection and retrieves
the web page content as a InputStream, which it returns as
a string.
*/
private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    /*
    Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
    web page content.
    */
    int len = 5000;
    String result = "[]";

    try {
        System.out.print("TRYING TO OPEN: " + myurl + "\n");
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setReadTimeout(30000 /* milliseconds */);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(30000 /* milliseconds */);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        connection.connect();
        int response = connection.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("HTTP CONNECTION :", "The response is: " + response);
        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        result = readIt(inputStream, len);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Most other SO answers I've come across refer to now deprecated code, thank you for reading.

Comment: Why are you not using modern network library instead, like Volley or OkHttp?

Comment: OkHttp looks even more convoluted to me, I'm looking through Volley now as it seems the more modern of the two. Thanks for the suggestions, I didn't know these existed.

Comment: Actually people says that OkHttp is more robust than the others, but i haven't tried it myself.